# VBA (excel) : Open a Wbk & copy/range (with ErrNumber 438)

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

Could you please tell me why the "not ok" line doesn't work ?

I try several methods to use a variable instead of using "CT.sheets("...")" 
but i don't unterstand why i get this ErrNumber.

Thanks for your answer.
thierry

```
Sub stackOVF_question_copyrange()
Set CT = ThisWorkbook
Set sh04 = Sheets("sh04_range_copy") '---or CT.Sheets("sh04_range_copy")
CFp = "C:\Users\thierry\Desktop"
CFn = "test_a.xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=CFp & "\" & CFn
Set CF = ActiveWorkbook
'--- with Range
CT.Sheets("sh04_range_copy").Range("A2:G3").Copy CF.Sheets(1).Range("A32") '---ok
'CT.sh04.Range("A2:G3").Copy CF.Sheets(1).Range("A32") '---nok VBA ErNum = 438
CF.Close (1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You should use `Set sh04 = CT.Sheets("sh04_range_copy")` and then `sh04.Range("A2:G3").copy ...`. The sheet is already defined by the workbook.

Comment: `Set CT = ThisWorkbook` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you SJR & Comintern for your speed answer. Quite clear and efficient-).

Comment: To clarify @Comintern's correct input, `CT.Sheets(...)` should be chaged to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(...)` - don't leave `Sheets`/`Worksheets` unqualified - `CT` is not needed because `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook that containss the VBA code that's running; not qualifying `Sheets` would query `ActiveWorkbook`, which may be a different workbook. You want that qualifier.